# Mongoose model unique

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I´m rather new to this..
If I dont want the user to be able to add duplicated countries to visitedCountry, shoulden unique true work?

Or are there any easy way to block that in the patch?

```
const User = mongoose.model('User', {
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  accessToken: {
    type: String,
    default: () => crypto.randomBytes(128).toString('hex')
  },
  visitedCountries:[ {
    country: {      
      type: Object,     
      ref: "Country",
      unique: true      
    },    
    comments: String     
  }]
})

app.patch('/countries', authenticateUser)
app.patch('/countries', async (req, res) => {
  const { username, visitedCountry  } = req.body
  try {        
    const countryByAlphaCode = await Country.findOne({ alphaCode: visitedCountry }).lean()      
    const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate({ username: username, }, {          
      $push: {        
        visitedCountries: { country: countryByAlphaCode, comments: "no comments yet"}
      },      
    }, { new: true })   
    res.json({ success: true, updatedUser })  
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: "Invalid request", error })
  }  
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options `unique` works for all documents. It prevents two (or more) documents from having the same value for your indexed field. It's often used for the email or username.

For your case, I recommend you to perform a check on the user data before you call `findOneAndUpdate`.